# True or False? The differential equation $y'=x^2 \sin y$ has infinitely many exceptional solutions.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am not sure what "infinitely many exceptional solutions" means exactly.
Need help interpreting this and working out a solution if needed.

---

I tried to work out a solution:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2 \sin y,$$

$$\frac{dy}{\sin(y)} = x^2 dx$$

$$ \csc(y)dy = x^2 dx$$

$$\int \csc(y)dy = \int x^2 dx$$

$$-\ln |\csc(y) + \cot(y)| = x^3/3 + C$$

Not sure how to work this out further.

Comment: You will want to isolate $y$ to determine the exceptional solutions.

Answer (score 1):

there are infinitely many ***constant*** solutions, $y = k \pi$ for integer $k.$ I guess one might call those exceptional.

In between consecutive such solutions, $\sin y$ keeps a fixed $\pm$ sign. Therefore one may make such a choice and solve for $y$ in your final equation.

Remember, this is first order, it is not permitted for solutions to cross or touch. Solutions may not cross the constant solutions as well.

The collection of all solutions resembles this picture: given any solution $y,$ we get other solutions with $2 \pi + y,$ $y - 2 \pi,$ finally $-y$ and  $2 \pi - y.$  As indicated in green, the constants $y=0,$ $y=\pi$ and so on are solutions as well, these are probably what your book means by exceptional solutions.

The image below was created using a recent technological innovation called [graph paper](http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph). You download this app onto treeware, then use "pens" to inscribe the image. What will they think of next.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a final answer but it is too long for a comment*.

Conserning the solution of the equation, you can make it simpler using the tangent hal-angle substitution $t=\tan(\frac y2)$. So, $$\int \frac {dy}{\sin(y)}=\int \frac {dt}{t}=\log(t)=\log(\tan(\frac y2))$$ From here $$y=2 \tan ^{-1}\left(c \,e^{\frac{x^3}{3}}\right)$$

*"infinitely many exceptional solutions"* probably means that, until you fix a condition, the integation constant provides as many solution as you want. The problem is that is true for any differential equation of any order $n$ as long as $n$ conditions are not given.

In this case, the problem is still more made a little more complex by the fact that $y$ is a periodic function which, moreover, is not defined for all arguments.

The phrasing of the problem looks rather ambiguous to me.

Answer (score 1):

An exceptional solution occurs when you have an initial condition that is not satisfied by your general solution.

$$-\ln|\csc(y)+\cot(y)| = \frac{x^3}{3} + C$$

Note that $\csc(y) + \cot(y) = \cot(\frac{y}{2})$

$$\ln|\cot(\frac{y}{2})| = \frac{-x^3}{3} + C$$
$$\Rightarrow y = 2\cot^{-1}\left(e^{-x^3/3}e^c\right)$$

Now suppose that $y(0) = a$

$$a = 2\cot^{-1}\left(e^0e^c\right)$$
$$\cot(\frac{a}{2}) = e^c$$

Substitute this into the original:

$$\Rightarrow y = 2\cot^{-1}\left(e^{-x^3/3}\cot\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\right)$$

But the inverse cotangent is undefined when evaluated at zero. We know that $e^x > 0$ and and $e^x$ is defined for all $x$, but

$$\cot(n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}) = 0, \cot(n\pi) =\textrm{undefined  for } n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Therefore, any initial value where $a = n\frac{\pi}{2}$ for some integer $n$ is exceptional (i.e. not covered by our general solution). This is because $\cot\frac{a}{2}$ is undefined, or we are attempting to evaluate the inverse cotangent at $0$, which is undefined.